# Reading a string line by line in python

Tags: python, string

I have the following string that is generated using `tkinter` and then read using `textEntry.get()`:

```
"
=========New Coffee Order===============
=========Bean Information===============
Type: Ethiopian
Origin: Single

=========Roaster/price==================
Steve's Beans
8.50/lb

Everyday Espresso
10.00/lb

Critical Coffee 
6.00/lb


=========End Coffee Order==============
"
```

I am trying to use fpdf to generate a pdf file of this information that follows a formatting guide. My question is this:

> How can I tell python to read a string in a way that interprets each line and not simply as a list of characters?

My initial idea was to tell python to read this string line by line and assign values to each line. However that seems like it might be inefficient, Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: How about `for line in text.split('\n'): ...`?

Comment: @DavyM It wasn't meant to be an answer. The question doesn't have enough detail to be answered. (If my comment is an acceptable answer, then surely the question is a duplicate.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`str.split('\n')` will do the trick:

```
In [135]: text.split('\n')
Out[135]: 
['"',
 '=========New Coffee Order===============',
 '=========Bean Information===============',
 'Type: Ethiopian',
 'Origin: Single',
 '',
 '=========Roaster/price==================',
 "Steve's Beans",
 '8.50/lb',
 '',
 'Everyday Espresso',
 '10.00/lb',
 '',
 'Critical Coffee ',
 '6.00/lb',
 '',
 '',
 '=========End Coffee Order==============',
 '"']
```

All you'll need to do is iterate over the returned list, line by line:

```
for line in text.split('\n'):
    ...
```

---

Comparing @Robᵩ's and my solutions:

```
In [137]: %timeit text.splitlines()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.8 µs per loop

In [138]: %timeit text.split('\n')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.31 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. All the answers below were helpful as well. This is exactly what I was looking to do, so thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 19):

[`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) converts a single multi-line string into a list of single-line strings.

Quoting the documentation:

> Return a list of the lines in the string, breaking at line boundaries. This method uses the universal newlines approach to splitting lines.

```
lines = text.splitlines()
```

Comment: @NoOrangeJuice, you can use the `str.splitlines()` in a loop `for line in text.splitlines():` to get each line of the text.

Comment: works in python3

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the lines are separated by UNIX line breaks, and the text is in a variable called `text`

```
lines = text.split("\n")
```

will do the job. You can then iterate over the list `lines` and do what you need to do to each line.