# python save data file to variable and search it

Tags: python

i have a python script where i need to search a particular log file, multiple times, at different part of the code.

i have been opening the log file at each part of the code. but it occurred to me how inefficient that was.

here is what im currently doing:

```
textfile = open(logfile, 'r')
filetext = textfile.read()
textfile.close()
matchesBegin = re.search(str(FirstEpoch), filetext)
matchesEnd = re.search(str(EndEpoch), filetext)
```

Then, at another part of the code that does separate things, I do this:

```
Everything = [ x.split(' ')[0][1:-1] for x in open(logfile).readlines() ]
```

Since the log file has already been opened and put in the "filetext" variable, I feel I shouldnt have to open it again.  So, i tried the following (which did not work!):

```
Everything = [ x.split(' ')[0][1:-1] for x in filetext ]
```

Hopefully, i have made clear what I'm trying to do here.  As mentioned, i have to scan the content of the log multiple times.  and each of those multiple times, i'm opening the log.  So, im asking; is it more efficient to open it once, save it to a variable and perform all future functions on that variable?  If so, how can the above code be fixed?

Comment: This may answer what you try to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979516/reading-a-string-line-by-line-in-python

Answer (score 0):

How I usually open files which I expect to be reasonable in size is simple:

```
filetext = textfile.readlines()
```

Now you have a list of the lines of the files.